# Find in time machine all versions of a file

Tags: macos, time-machine

I want to find in time machine a file on my mac that once existed. I know that this file has been created and deleted several times in the past but I don't remember when that happened. I need to be sure to find all the versions of this file.

So what would help me is a way to search the complete history in time machine.
Can this be done? How?

Comment: Hi, [does this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230154/getting-all-versions-of-a-file-from-a-time-machine-backup) answer your question?

Comment: @ Lulucmy That might be working, but I would prefer a method provided by Time Machine itself...